# Issue achieving a div setup

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to explain my issue with an image but unfortunately it seems I cant post one jet so ill try to explain my question as well as I can. I need in the body of my website 2 divs (containers) top part white and bottom part grey. Then there needs to be a blue box floating exactly in the middle of these 2 containers, not with a 100% width but around 80%.
In the containers are icons that need to be clear and wont go under the blue box.
Im have tried to do it with position relative and get a minus top in there but obviously that didnt work at all as it fell apart responsive wise.
What can i do to make this happen well?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="icon2"></div>
   <p class="txt-fix-2">....</p>
   <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
  </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <div class="icon1"></div>
        <p class="txt-fix-2">...</p>
        <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
         <div class="icon2"></div>
          <p class="txt-fix-2">.....</p>
          <p class="txt-fix-3">......</P>
         </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
           <div class="icon1"></div>
            <div class="primero-bot-icons"> 
             <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-3">
               <div class="icon2"></div>
                <p class="txt-fix-2">...</p>
                <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
               </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                 <div class="icon1"></div>
                  <p class="txt-fix-2">....</p>
                  <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
                 </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                   <div class="icon2"></div>
                    <p class="txt-fix-2">...</p>
                    <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
                   </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                     <div class="icon1"></div>
                      <p class="txt-fix-2">...</p>
                      <p class="txt-fix-3">...</P>
                     </div>
                    <div>
                     <p class="bot-btn-bg">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary extra">&nbsp;> pri</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary extra">> ...</button>
                     </p>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                   <p class="txt-fix-2">.....</p>
                   <p class="txt-fix-3">.....</P>
                 </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Holy divitis Batman!

Comment: How about an image of what this is supposed to look like? You may not be able to add the actual image in the question but you could like to an offsite image

Comment: ah great stuff, http://s22.postimg.org/65n51bdk1/setup.png this is what I am hoping to achieve. Ive used twitter bootstrap alot in the site. I hope you can help me out :)

Comment: That part is simple enough...but I'm unclear on how the icons will be arranged and interact (if at all) with the blue box.

Comment: All I am hoping is that when you work with that responive the icons wont go under the blue box, I figured I should use a z-index on the containers. This is the CSS I use for the icons if it helps anything. .icon1{
  background: url(http://s8.postimg.org/756txg82p/icon1.png)center no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-size:auto 5vw;
  margin-top:20px;
}

Comment: When you say not go under...how should they react...wrap around what? I'm curious as to the final design because I'm not sure of what you are trying to do. Also, what is the height of the blue box...is it supposed to be flexible?

Comment: Sorry that my explanation is so confusing but this should fix it - this is a photoshopped image of what I am hoping to achieve. http://s21.postimg.org/tbz9fbimf/setup2.png I want to enter some text and 2 buttons in the box, so I guess it only needs to scale well or be removed for mobile viewing. whatever would be best.